# Playing Dailymotion or any free server like tune.pk or video weed video in my android application is legal or not?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-video-player, dailymotion-api

i want to play Daily Motion videos or videoweed or any free server.. but i am affraid of getting suspention by google play.. i also need authenticate info about it as google don't give you another chance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a law office. Please consult with qualified legal counsel regarding the relevant laws in your country and the terms of service of your app distribution channels (e.g., Play Store).

Comment: but Stack overflow has that experienced developers who can help me in this case, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use webView to stream video or you can use this dailymotion sdk
https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-android/tree/master/WebSDKProject

-Cheers